# Range query for date of "long" field type in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I have a field in ES type representing date with `long` type.

I am trying to filter data in kibana based on this field.
For example, get me the documents created in last seven days. But not able to come up with the solution.

In Kibana Visualization page, right now i have created like,

`(events.time:[1458325800000 TO * ]) AND (event.type:"login")`

But I need something like this

`(events.time:[now-7d TO * ]) AND (event.type:"login")`

I do not want to change the data type from 'long' to 'date' as it is not in my hands.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot do date queries on a non date field. Maybe I understand the question wrong.

Comment: I also think, it is not possible. But I want to make sure it